# Android - Save text and launching an Activity with the same button

Tags: android, button, android-intent, android-activity, onclicklistener

I'm currently working in an Activity which saves text from three EditViews and constructs a SQL query. After that, the query is given to another activity to search and display the results.

Right now I've got two buttons, one to save the query, inside an onClickListener and another button to start the second activity:

```
searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            //First the data from the editviews is saved    
            EditText searchName = (EditText) findViewById(com.pedro.books.R.id.search_name);
            search_name = searchName.getText().toString();
            searchName.setText("");
            EditText searchAut = (EditText) findViewById(com.pedro.books.R.id.search_aut);
            search_aut = searchAut.getText().toString();
            searchAut.setText("");
            EditText searchYea = (EditText) findViewById(com.pedro.books.R.id.search_yea);
            search_yea = searchYea.getText().toString();
            searchYea.setText("");

            //here i construct the query    
    });
```

And with an onClick in the xml code, I start the activity with another button:

```
public void ReadResults(View view){
    //The query is given to the ReadActivity to display the results
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ReadActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(ReadActivity.EXTRA_QUERY, query);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

I've tried with the same button for both without changing anything and it obviously doesn't work, and I've also tried to start the activity inside the onClickListener, but I got this error: **"The constructor Intent(new View.OnClickListener(){}, Class) is undefined"**

Is there a way to start the activity inside the onClickListener or to stop the second activity to start until the query is saved?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are putting the intent in the onClick of a button you cannot use `this` you need to use `YourActivity.this` to properly get context.

`this` in your button is your `OnClickListener` like the error says

Answer (score -2):

Where/How do you call your ReadResults method? On a side note - does it need to be public? If you call it inside the clickListener handler then that's wrong.
1) Extract your code out of the clickListener handler and have it into a private method within your activity class.
2) Your clickListener should only call that private method.
3) You could have your 3 editboxes as memebers of your activity and instantiate them onCreate() instead of getting them each time you click the button, it's expensive parsing the UI if not necessary.